# Driver returns null value : appium

Tags: java, appium

I have this following code where I am searching for an element in current activity. However, the driver is returning null value.

```
try
    {
    String ca = ((AndroidDriver) driver).currentActivity();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logs :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver cannot be cast to class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver (io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver and io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I tried changing the *driver* cast to AppiumDriver. Does not work even then,whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the way you defined the driver instance, don't use generic `AppiumDriver` and avoid casting:

```java
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumURL, capabilities);
...
String cActivity = driver.currentActivity();
```

works perfectly.